# Converting text file into 2-dim array in python

Tags: python

I have a text file (let's call it file.txt) of containing only 1 line of this type:

```
[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15]
```

I want to convert that into a 2-dim array in python so that I will get

```
[[1 2 3]

[4 5 6]

[7 8 9]

[10 11 12]

[12 14 15]]
```

I tried using

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:

data = f.readlines()

c = np.array(data)

print(c)

c.dtype
```

But it returns me `['[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]']` and `dtype('<U34')`

Can somebody help me with this?

Ps. Above is just an example. In reality I will work on arbitrary size 2-dim array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `json` to help you

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    content = "[" + f.read() + "]"

values = json.loads(content)

values_np = np.array(values)
```

Comment: Thank you. That's useful.

I am new to coding world and new to stack overflow forum. 

I realized you changed the text (code) in my question. Just how did you type the code in that nice format? Sorry if this is noob question to you.

Comment: @user19532602 click on `edit` below your post and you'll see it, it used ` (backquote)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***eval***

```
import numpy as np

str_array = open('file.txt', 'r').read()

arr = np.array(eval(str_array))
```